# add image to FileField in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django building a website and I'm trying to let the user upload an image to be used, here is my files :

**settings.py**

```
# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home2/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**models.py**

```
class test1(models.Model):
    dress_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='dress')
    dress_size = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='5')
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d',default ='upload')
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    all_dress = test1.objects.all()
    context = {
        'all_dress': all_dress,
    }
    return render(request, 'fostania/home.html', context)
```

and here is how I used it in my template

**HTML**

```
    {% for item in all_dress %}

        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ item.docfile.url }}" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ item.dress_name }}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{ item.dress_size }}</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
                              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

      {% endfor %}
```

**URLS.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.template.context_processors import static
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from dress import settings
from fostania import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    path('home/',views.home, name='home'),
    path('add/',views.add, name="add"),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

finally, the image never shows .. it is always an error in the link !!

Please note that image goes there in the static/media file after uploading, So i think it is some kind of URL error!

**ERROR**

The error is that the image always shows a broken link, and when I open the link (Open images link ) it gives me this error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/documents/2018/05/18/test_dress3.jpg
```

Comment: Please provide the error you are receiving.

Comment: Also, view the source of your HTML page and see if the correct url is generated in the `src` attribute of the `img` element. To check if the url is correct, copy and paste the url in a different tab to see if the image is loading.

Comment: Please check updates for the error , and the HTML src link is the same one requested in the error

Comment: While I try to figure this out please change the code to use `ImageField()` if you are only uploading images in your project.

Comment: Are you in production or development? You have to use `collectstatic` command in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED** 
it was a wrong import reference, I used `from django.conf.urls.static import static` instead of  `from django.template.context_processors import static` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `MEDIA_URL` to the project's urlpattern list:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Check related part of the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/).

Comment: it gives me an error `TypeError: static() got an unexpected keyword argument 'document_root'`

Comment: @AhmedWagdi are you sure you are copied code correcly? Can you add your `urls.py` file to the question?